# How to decrypt CMS /PKCS#7 with node forge

Tags: encryption, cmd, pkcs#7, node-forge

I try to decode a CMS /PKCS#7 with node forge. Private key and data are in files. Key is PEM, data is DER. That's my code:

```
import forge from 'node-forge'
import fs from 'fs';

let data = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/data');
let Key = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/key'); 
let pkeyAsn1 = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(Key); 

let p7 = forge.pkcs7;
let asndata =forge.util.createBuffer(data);
let msg = p7.messageFromAsn1(forge.asn1.fromDer(asndata));
console.log(msg.decrypt(msg.recipients[0], pkeyAsn1));
```

But the output is undefined. The openssl equivalent

```
openssl cms -decrypt -inform DER -in data -inkey key -out test
```

works

Comment: I am seeing the same behaviour; undefined output and no errors. Did you resolve this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Just to help all those who may come across this in the future, the solution is as follows:

```
...
msg.decrypt(msg.recipients[0], pkeyAsn1);
let data = msg.content.data;
```